# Monge method for second order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm tring to solve a non-linear partial differential equation of second order using Monge method. I noticed that one of the subsidiary equations has no real solution. It has the form $$A dp^2 + 2 B dpdq + C dq^2$$  with $A, B, C$ functions of $x,y,z,p,q$ and $B^2-AC<0$.

The differential equation is of elliptical type.

Is there another method to start?

Answer (score 0):

The question is badly put.

$A dp^2 + 2 B dpdq + C dq^2$ isn't an equation. There is no equal in it. One can suppose that the equation is :
$$A (dp)^2 + 2 B (dp)(dq) + C (dq)^2=0 \tag 1$$
What are $p$ and $q$ ? Without context nobody knows.

One can suppose that this comes from an PDE with unknown function $u(x,y)$ with $p=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and  $q=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ the solutions of the next equation :
$$A\:K^2+2B\:K+C=0\quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}
K_1=\frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-AC}}{A}\\
K_2=\frac{-B-\sqrt{B^2-AC}}{A}
\end{cases}$$
Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to :
$$(dp-K_1dq)(dp-K_2dq)=0 \tag 2$$
They are two first order linear PDE to be solved for two independant sets of solutions :
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-K_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 \tag 3$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-K_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 \tag 4$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The question is that the roots K1 and K2 are imaginary.

Comment: Doesn't matter if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are real or complex. The solutions are $u(x,y)=F(y+K_1x)$ and $u(x,y)=G(y+K_2x)$ with arbitrart real or complex functions $F$ and $G$ .

Comment: But then u(x,y) has always an imaginary part. am I right?  I need a real function u(x,y)

Comment: Since there is an arbitrary function involved in $u(x,y)$ which mignt be complex, one cannot definitively answer without knowing the boundary condition in order to determine the arbitrary function.